# Изменение текста в PSD средствами php

Tags: php, photoshop, psd

столкнулся со следующей задачей: Необходимо автоматизировать печать сертификата, в котором уникальные (имя, промокод, и даты действия сертификата). Сертификат сейчас в виде psd файла, в котором приходится, каждый раз вручную менять имя пользователя. Можно ли как-то средствами php отредактировать текст в этом PSD файле, или возможно перевести в другой формат, в котором в дальнейшем можно будет редактировать текст и конвертировать в jpg. Подскажите пожалуйста, что и как можно сделать.

P.S. Про переменные в фотошопе знаю, но хотелось бы это полностью автоматизировать через php (чтобы клиентам от определенной суммы заказа, автоматом создавался и печатался сертификат и промокод в бд сайта добавлялся)

Comment: на jpeg подложку средствами GD текст добавляйте тогда да и все дела. Если какие-либо эффекты там отсутствуют на тексте

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему следующим образом: Сохранил картинку в jpeg без нужных частей текста, там просто оставил пробелы, и через GD подключил нужные шрифты и вывел на картинку нужные данные. Всё автоматизированно!!!